# Doctrine - Remap and convert a already existing entity

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm learning the Doctrine ORM and I'm loving, but I have a question about how remap a already mapped entity.

I created some of attributes in my table, and I want to map them to my entity. The problem is that I have some of business rule methods on my entity and I can' t lose them, so I need to remap the class and convert to entity without lose the already existed methods.

Actually I use the commands below:

```
php doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database --force annotation /path/project/models
php doctrine orm:generate:entities --update-entities --generate-methods=1 /path/project/models
```

So, you can help me? How?